# Add & Remove character to text field with one button

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to make an add & remove ± operator with one button.

So at the beginning ' - ' is supposed to be not available. When I click on ' - ', it should get added in the first line of the text field. If it is already present and we click on it again, it should get removed. How do I do this?

This is the code I have written so far:

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    jTextField.setText( "-" + jTextField.getText());
}
```

Comment: Make the 'button' a `JCheckBox`. When it is checked, get the text, check that it does not already start with '-' and if not, prefix the text with one. When it is unchecked, do the same check (but opposite, and if it does, get the substring from the first character and set it as text. Look carefully through the `String` methods for details. Note also that all the checks are necessary because the user could always just type a `-` sign manually. Which really sounds simpler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = jTextField.getText();
        if (text != null && text.indexOf("-") == 0) {
            text = "+" + text.substring(1, text.length());
        } 
        else if (text != null && text.indexOf("+") == 0) {
            text = "-" + text.substring(1, text.length());
        }
        else {
            text = "-"+(text != null ? text : "");
        }
        jTextField.setText(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no text, what text is to be added?

Try this out:

```
    private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
            if(jTextField.getText().length() != 0)
            {
                jTextField.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                //Set the text from wherever you are receiving it
            }
    }
```

When your field is empty, you can set the text to whatever you want, and if it is not, it will be made empty.

Comment: not quite right tho. he wants a button, which will add or remove the `-` depending on whether its in the textfield or not. at least that's what i understand

Comment: there is have number already input with another button, not empty, this is for calculator app.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Wow, I thought the content of the field needs to be added or removed.

Comment: @MUHAMMADNAUFALAZKIA can you post your code to get an idea what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

did not test this, but it should work:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (textField.getText().charAt(0) == '-') {
            String toSet = textField.getText();
            toSet = toSet.substring(0, 0).replace("-", "");
            textField.setText(toSet);
        } else {
            textField.setText("-" + textField.getText());
        }

    }

});
```

feel free to ask if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

I'd add on a new ActionListener to the button and define it's code with an @Override statement. This should do the trick:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String fieldText = textField.getText();

                if (fieldText.substring(0,1).equals("-")){
                    textField.setText(fieldText.substring(1, fieldText.length()));
                } else {
                    textField.setText("-" + fieldText);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A different take on the idea which is a little more efficient, as you're not create so many temporary `String` objects

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Document doc = field.getDocument();
        try {
            if (doc.getLength() > 0 && doc.getText(0, 1).equals("-")) {
                doc.remove(0, 1);
            } else {
                doc.insertString(0, "-", null);               
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```